# Elixir: rationale behind allowing rebinding of variables

Tags: erlang, elixir

What is the rationale behind allowing rebinding of variables in Elixir, when Erlang doesn't allow that?

Answer (score 11):

Most functional languages don't allow rebinding of variables in the same scope. So Elixir allowing this does definitely give it an non-functional, imperative feel. Erlang's problem is rather lack of scope, or to be more precise that there is only one scope in a whole function clause. We did have serious discussions whether to introduce scope but in the end we decided against it as it was backwards incompatible with the existing system. And developers hate backwards inconsistent changes.

The Erlang way has one serious benefit: when you get it wrong you generally get an error so you can **SEE** the mistake. This compared just getting strange behaviour when a variable doesn't have the value you expect it to have which is **MUCH** harder to detect and correct.

Personally I think that the problem of new variable names, for example using the number scheme, is greatly overblown. Compared to the time it takes me to work out **WHAT** I am going to do changing variable names is trivial. And after a while you just see it without reflecting about it. Honestly.

**EDIT:**

Also when chaining data through a sequence of functions the actual meaning of the data changes so reusing the same variable name can be very misleading. It can end up just meaning a generic "data I am passing from one function to another".

Comment: Agreed. I think the examples with numbered variables are either contrived or just show poor coding. Repeatedly passing results from one function as arguments to the next function cries out for folding, not variable rebinding.

Comment: @SteveVinoski or it cries out for the pipelining which is an idea that a few FP languages have adopted.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I have a problem with term "pipelining" and what it refers to. To me as an old Unix user and concurrent programmer the word "pipe" screams out concurrency and parallelism while the way it has been defined in some functional languages has nothing to do with either. It is just used as syntactic sugar for nested function calls. While that may be useful in itself it should be called something else the term will lose all meaning.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the rationale straight from the horse's mouth:

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/01/comparing-elixir-and-erlang-variables/

Answer (score 6):

Because it's simpler.

Take a look at [this question](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-May/043697.html) posted to the Erlang mailing list in 2009.  Specifically this part:

---

> > I like pattern matching in the majority of cases, but I find I write
> >     enough code where I need to incrementally update a data structure, and
> >     maintaining that code is a pain when I have code like:

```
X = foo(),
X1 = bar(X),
X2 = xyzzy(X1),
blah(X2).
```

> > and later want to change it to:

```
X = foo(),
X1 = whee(X),
X2 = bar(X1),
X3 = xyzzy(X2),
blah(X3).
```

***Editor's note--this is the reply to that question.***

> This goes through IRC a lot.  This is a result of poor variable naming
>   practice, and there is no need to introduce rebinding to "fix" it;
>   just stop using single letters and counters as variable names.
>
> If for example that was written

```
 FooStateX    = foo(),
 PostBarX     = bar(FooStateX),
 OnceXyzziedX = xyzzy(PostBarX),
 blah(OnceXyzziedX).
```

---

The code demonstrated there isn't all that uncommon in Erlang (note the remark  "this goes through IRC a lot"). Elixir's ability to simply rebind names saves us from having to generate new dummy names for things all the time.  That's all. It's wise to bear in mind that the original creators of Erlang weren't trying to build a functional language.  They were simply pragmatic developers who had a problem to solve.  Elixir's approach is simple pragmatism.

Comment: Yes, but rebinding means I lose the unique meaning of a variable. I now have to actually scan through all code to find out what a variable means just now. That complicates things. This I think is worse than having to generate new names. Also when passing data through the actual **meaning** can change so reusing a variable name means that it has just become a dummy name.

Comment: This is an interesting conversation Robert and certainly one I'd rather have in a forum where we have more room to spell out our thinking on this. I understand exactly what you're getting at but there are also pragmatic issues; places where allowing rebinding is a more pragmatic approach than functional purity.

Comment: Onorio start a discussion about it on the elixir mailing list and I will get into it.