# Are Elixir structs really immutable?

Tags: struct, erlang, elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

I'm currently studying Elixir and I'm reading "**Functional Web Development with Elixir, OTP and Phoenix**", which imo is a great book.
Working at the state machine chapter, I came up with the following code:

```
defmodule IslandsEngine.Rules do
  alias __MODULE__

  defstruct state: :initialized

  def new(), do: %Rules{}

  def check(%Rules{state: :initialized} = rules, :add_player), do:
    {:ok, %Rules{rules | state: :players_set}}

  def check(_state, _action), do: :error

end
```

The code above should work as a fully functional state machine.
I'll paste above a few of **iex** commands:

```
iex(1)> alias IslandsEngine.Rules
IslandsEngine.Rules

iex(2)> rules = Rules.new()
%IslandsEngine.Rules{state: :initialized}

iex(3)> {:ok, rules} = Rules.check(rules, :add_player)
{:ok, %IslandsEngine.Rules{state: :players_set}}

iex(4)> rules.state
:players_set
```

So as you can see, the state struct has changed from `:initialized` to `:add_player`. Great.

My question is: is `state:` struct really immutable? I mean, the method `check/1` returns a copy of the struct with a `state: :players_set` statement, which follows a correct functional pattern... but how does it "overwrite" the current status without modifying it directly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just realized there is an existing question with answers that cover this in much more detail: [Are Elixir variables really immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967086/are-elixir-variables-really-immutable)

Comment: Another interesting Q/A which might clear up a few more things: [Elixir: Rationale behind allowing rebinding of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304252/elixir-rationale-behind-allowing-rebinding-of-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elixir data-structures are indeed immutable. But what happens is that **function calls return a completely new value** (that is different from the original depending on the function you called).

As for the "changing the variable's value", [that's an added feature](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-May/043697.html) in `Elixir` (over the original `Erlang` language). The variable's value doesn't actually change, it's just rebinded to the new one. The old ones are automatically garbage collected by the `Erlang VM.`

---

So in your example:

```ex
# This returns a completely new `%Rules{}` struct and rebinds
# the `rules` variable to the new term
{:ok, rules} = Rules.check(rules, :add_player)
```